# I have a problem with the "Féminin" and "Masculin"

Tags: genre

I'm a Moroccan dialect native speaker, and I have a good French, but I still have a problem that I think in Moroccan about objects and things. For example a question in French is feminine whereas in the Moroccan language is masculine, so it is quite likely for me to say "un question" instead of "une question".

I want to ask if there a solution for this problem so I can think completely in French.

Comment: Habits. It's just a way of thinking, to determine what could be feminine, and what could be masculine. Only experience can help you. There is quite a "big" kind of thing that will be of some type, but there is always exceptions.

Comment: Related: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/is-there-any-general-rule-to-determine-the-gender-of-a-noun-based-on-its-spellin

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is a generic solution to your problem; genders tend to be language specific and while while a lot of them are the same across languages some are not (e.g. die Sonne in German vs. le soleil in French).

As far as I know all French nouns ending in -tion are always feminine.

Comment: Of course there is always at least one exception. For instance, *un bastion*.

Comment: And since you mention it, there is actually very little correlation (if any at all) between German and French. Correlation with other romance languages (e.g. Spanish or Italian) is much higher.