# L'origine du genre des noms

Tags: étymologie, genre, origine-ou-raison

Quand on commence à étudier le français (FLE), l'on apprend qu'il vaut mieux apprendre de nouveaux mots accompagnés de leur déterminant. Cependant, il existe des règles (soit de sens, soit de terminaison) qui peuvent nous aider. Bien sûr, il existe aussi des cas qui violent ces règles. Je me demande comment s'expliquent ces exceptions.

Par exemple:

> La majorité des mots en -age sont masculins. Des exceptions notables
>   sont la cage, la plage, la nage, la page (d'un livre), la plage, la
>   rage.
>
> Très beaucoup mots en -ce sont féminins; or, e.g., le silence est
>   masculin.
>
> Les mots en -ée sont normalement féminins mais des mots comme lycée,
>   musée, apogée, Élysée, mausolée, etc. sont masculins.

Il y a évidement d'autres cas. D'habitude, d'où viennent ces genres d'exceptions ?

Comment: "Cilice", "orifice" et "service" sont masculins, au moins.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi attention cependant pour "Cilice", la forme masculine désigne une étoffe, tandis que " la silice" (féminin donc) désigne l'élément chimique.  (d'ailleurs je ne connaissait que la forme féminine, tu viens de m'apprendre quelque chose, merci :) )

Comment: Merci:-)! Mais la question demeurent. Ce sont des exceptions. Pourquoi par exemple silence et service sont masculin bien que la majorité des mots en -ce soient féminins ?

Comment: Environ 10 % des mots en -ce sont masculins, par exemple : appendice, armistice, artifice, bénéfice, calice, caprice, commerce, dentifrice, divorce, délice, exercice, face-à-face, hospice, indice, interstice, maléfice, palace, pouce, prépuce, rapace, silence, solstice... La corrélation est forte, mais loin d'être parfaite. Avec -age, c'est bien mieux, mais il manque à la liste image comme mot courant, et hypallage qui l'est moins ;-)

Comment: Pour une liste de terminaisons fortement corrélées avec un genre, j'avais posté [un graphique et un tableau ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16781/1109).

Comment: Pour ce qui est de ta dernière catégorie d'exceptions (ée)... voyons dimitris...  Λύκειον, Μουσεῖον, απογειον, Ἠλύσιον,... tu devrais le savoir bien mieux que nous... ;-)

Comment: @aCOSwt Justement:-)! Ce sont des neutres dans la langue grecque. Pourquoi alors est-ils devenus masculins en français et pas féminins ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Je ne pense pas que les exceptions "viennent de quelque part". Il y a des règles qui font que quand un mot est formé d'une certaine manière, il prend un certain genre. Par exemple, un mot formé à partir d'un verbe auquel on rajoute le suffixe "-age" est de genre masculin. Mais certains mots se terminent de la même manière sans avoir été formés de cette manière, et il ne suivent pas la règle. S'ils sont du même genre c'est une coïncidence, s'ils n'en sont pas c'est comme ça. Par exemple le mot "plage" vient du latin "plaga" qui était féminin. Comment expliquer pourquoi il ne suit pas la règle ? Il n'y a pas de raison ; c'est comme ça. Il n'y a pas de règle générale qui explique pourquoi : chaque exception est une... exception.

Pour résumer : il y a des règles du type "si un mot est formé de telle manière, alors il prendra telle terminaison et sera de tel genre". L'erreur est de croire que tous les mots qui ont cette terminaison auront été formé en suivant la règle et donc prendront le même genre.

(Et à mon avis vouloir apprendre le genre des mots avec des règles est une erreur. Elles peuvent donner des tendances, mais si c'est pour se tromper une fois sur trois au lieu d'une fois sur deux, ça ne sert pas à grand chose...)

Comment: J'ajouterai que les erreurs de genre qu'on peut entendre parfois, c'est tellement mignon ;) Et ce n'est souvent pas critique pour la compréhension (hormis pour les mots qui ont les 2 formes masculine et féminine qui ne veulent pas du tout dire la même chose mais dans ces cas-là le contexte lève presque toujours toute ambiguïté).

Answer (score 0):

Dans le cas des mots en -ée, ils sont normalement féminins certes mais des mots comme lycée, musée, apogée, Élysée, mausolée, etc. sont masculins car ils viennent du grec via ou non le latin, leur terminaison y était respectivement « os » ou « on », et « us » ou « um » francisée en e muet. Ainsi Λύκειον est latinisé en Lyceum, le « um » s'amuït en e muet mais néanmoins écrit, et l'on a Lycée, du neutre en grec et en latin, du masculin en français (très peu de neutres en français et à ma connaissance pas de noms). Morpheus donne de la même manière Morphée, dieu du sommeil et non déesse ! S'il n'y avait que des règles comme celle-là, ou la célébrissime « bijou caillou chou genou hibou joujou pou », ce serait simple …

En tout cas, le conseil fervent que je donne à ceux qui apprennent le français en langue étrangère (FLE), surtout les anglophones dont la grammaire est euh rudimentaire en comparaison, est de mémoriser **par cœur le genre** des noms, les règles ne sont que des aides imparfaites. Personnellement j'ai encore un mal de chien avec les substantifs en allemand parce que je n'ai pas ou trop peu fait ce type d'effort dans mes premières années !