# La longue « post-acute sequelae of SARS-CoV-2 infection » et le sigle PASC ?

Tags: vocabulaire, terminologie, comparaison-de-langues, santé-et-médecine, acronymes

> "Many of you are now aware of what had long been called 'long COVID,'
> " said Fauci, the White House COVID-19 Response Team's chief medical
> adviser. "But actually, what that really is is post-acute sequelae of
> SARS-CoV-2 infection, which we're now referring to as 'PASC,' or
> P-A-S-C." (Dr Anthony Fauci, sur [Medscape](https://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/946419), le 24 février 2021)

Dans une [revue](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41591-021-01283-z) récente de la littérature sur le sujet on trouve aussi « Post-acute COVID-19 syndrome ». Il y aurait un certain nombre de [formes concurrentes](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26558582), comme avec le terme « chronic ». Le [GDT](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=26558582) donne « syndrome post-COVID-19 ». Quant à l'emploi plus courant/familier « long COVID », [Termium](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=CHRONIC%20COVID-19&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs) recense *COVID-19 de longue durée, ...au long cours, ...longue*. Il n'est pas exactement clair si la notion formelle se démarque de celle plus courante en ce sens qu'on parle d'après la phase aiguë ou après le début des symptômes couramment associés à l'infection alors qu'une certaine proportion de personnes [seraient](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/global-health/science-and-disease/significant-number-long-covid-asymptomatic-first-infected-study/) touchées sans avoir eu de symptômes particuliers.

- La précision demande-t-elle qu'on réfère à la *phase aiguë* (*acute*)
  dans « syndrome post-COVID-19 » et ce dernier est-il le plus courant ou adéquat
  et a-t-on un sigle qui y réfère ?
- Quelle formulation avec *long(ue)* est-elle la plus fréquente
  couramment ?

Answer (score 2):

En France, le nom le plus courant et largement utilisé par la presse est ***[covid long](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covid_long)***.

Le féminin n'a pas (encore?) affecté cette forme composée.

Comment: Si j'en crois mon expérience quotidienne, le féminin n'a pas affecté la forme simple non plus, ou alors seulement par certaines personnes fières de leur pédanterie.

Comment: @mouviciel J'ai failli écrire *n'a pas encore **infecté** cette forme...* mais je me suis retenu en pensant que ça pouvait être pris comme une réflexion sexiste. Malheureusement on lit et entend de plus en plus le féminin dans la presse et à la télé. S'il gagne, lors d'une future réforme orthographique, ça deviendra peut-être ***la covide***...

Comment: Ici à Toulouse on dit déjà **le covide**.

Comment: Oui, la prononciation est une chose mais je parlais surtout de l'écrire comme ça pour lui donner un air plus "français". On commence à trouver pas mal de *covide* d'ailleurs.

Comment: Si le féminin en venait à l'emporter, *covide* me semblerait plus approprié. Il ne s'agit que de mon opinion personnelle, bien sûr: le fait est que ce genre de changement serait chaudement débattu, des fissures apparaîtraient dans les relations familiales, de stériles mais interminables débats s'engageraient dans les réseaux sociaux, l'Académie et autres autorités linguistiques en profiteraient pour peigner cette girafe plutôt que de se frotter à d'autres problèmes plus sérieux. Mais les caricaturistes de tout poil pourraient au moins nous faire rire et sourire un peu dans la tourmente.

Comment: @Pasunclue Pour jeter un peu plus d'huile sur le feu en croyant bien faire, on pourrait soutenir **la·le covid·e** ;-)

Comment: @némésie-t-île Si le mot avait été présenté par les media directement au féminin, il aurait été adopté ainsi et il n'y aurait pas de problème. Mon désamour pour ce féminin tient d'une part à ce qu'il a été promu trop tard et que ça a généré une confusion inutile, et d'autre part parce qu'il ne s'intègre pas bien à nos habitudes : 99.031% des mots se terminant par un *D* sont masculins en français, d'après ce que j'avais [calculé à l'époque](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/16781/1109). S'il fallait choisir un suffixe conforme aux usages, je proposerais la **covite**.