# Is there any ways to help me learn un and une?

Tags: grammaire

I was wondering if there is any way to tell the difference between masculine and feminine versions of a.

For example, why is in une pizza instead of un pizza?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any general rule to determine the gender of a noun based on its spelling?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2616/is-there-any-general-rule-to-determine-the-gender-of-a-noun-based-on-its-spellin)

Comment: Words are arbitrary, so sadly there is no "why/because," but there are tendencies based on other arbitrary tendencies from related languages all going back to further arbitrary older tendencies and rules in roots of Latin, Greek, PIE...we all wonder.  Please see the related questions.