# How do we know which is a masculine noun or a feminine noun?

Tags: grammaire, articles

I have a French exam about le,la,les and l' but I'm not familiar with le and la because I don't know which is masculine noun and feminine noun. Is there any difference?

Comment: Possibile duplicate : http://french.stackexchange.com/q/329/7321

Comment: There is no absolute rule, you have to learn for every word. French isn't easy :P

Comment: There is no rule, but there are some [hints](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/16781/1109)