# Why 'The tie' or 'La cravate' is feminine in French?

Tags: vocabulaire, genre

I am a beginer in learning French. I came to see this sentence somewhere.

> "La cravate" - The tie.

I am curious why 'the tie' is a feminine word?

Comment: Most English nouns do not have grammatical gender, so what do you mean? Related : [Is there any general rule to determine the gender of a noun based on its spelling?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2616/358), [Comment fait-on pour reconnaître et mémoriser le genre des noms ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/329/358).

Comment: My question is based on the answer given by @Circeus, 'nontechnical words whose pronunciation ends in /-at/ tends to be strongly feminine'

Comment: @ShubhamBhave The word "cravate" ends in "ate" in the spelling, which means /at/ in the pronunciation (notice the slashes). Circeus means if you actually hear /at/ at the end of a word it's probably feminine.

Comment: Not every word ending in e in French is feminine by a long shot. There is not always a reason. Are we going to go through the entire dictionary?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd wager that's because in French, baring other factors (e.g. certain suffixes), nontechnical words whose pronunciation ends in /-at/ tends to be strongly feminine. If that specific sense was borrowed from German, it's probably borrowed in the same gender (*Krawatte* is also feminine in German).

It's however not entirely clear what the sequence of borrowing was (it's ultimately from Croatian *hrvat*, which also gave, well, *croate*).

Otherwise, this is really threading into the most arbitrary aspect of language (especially if you're gonna follow this up with "why are words in /-at/ feminine?"). Asking "why does this language function differently" is typically not much more useful a question as asking "why do different languages exist". French has grammatical gender. No matter what the word is, if it's a noun, it's going to have a gender, and this sort of categorization is going to have some level of arbitrariness by definition.